# Linking parts of a single-page web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am working on a single-page web site targeted for mobile users (eventually going to be ported to Phonegap). I have broken down my screens into 'cards', which are basically just `<div>`s that I am showing/initializing/hiding as needed.

Currently I am having trouble deciding on the proper structure to use in order to implement linking these panels together into a coherent app. My current implementation goes something like this (currently using Knockout as I am familiar with it):

```
//Javascript
var LoginCard = function() {
    this.goToRegister = function() { 
        // IF registerCard is not initialized
        // THEN ko.applyBindings(new RegisterCard(), document.getElementById('registerCard'));
        // ELSE $('#registerCard').show();
    };
    this.doLogin = function() { /* Goes to home card after login */ };
}
var RegisterCard = function() {
    this.goToLogin = function() { /* Goes back to login card */ };
    this.doRegister = function() { /* Goes to login card after reg */ };
}
ko.applyBindings(new LoginCard(), document.getElementById('loginCard'));

//HTML
<div id="loginCard">
    <button data-bind="click: goToRegister" id="btnReg">Register Account</button>
    <button data-bind="click: doLogin" id="btnLogin">Login</button>
</div>
<div id="registerCard">
    <button data-bind="click: goToLogin" id="btnBackToLogin">Back To Login</button>
    <button data-bind="click: doRegister" id="btnDoReg">Submit Registration</button>
</div>
```

As you can see, the linking occurs within the view model itself, so the different view models (e.g. loginCard, registerCard, homeCard) become tightly coupled with each other.

A more "low-level" alternative would just be to use jQuery to bind the button events so that each card does not have to know details about the other cards:

```
//But this means I have to specify a ton of unique IDs for all the elements in the page.
$('#btnReg').click(function() { /* Initialize and go to registerCard. */ });
```

I also thought of using hash-routing/pushState so while the click events are still inside each view model, all it has to know is the URL to go to? Something like:

```
var LoginCard = function() {
    this.goToRegister = function() { 
        window.location.hash = 'register';
        //or history.pushState('state', '', 'register';
    };
}
```

This is my first attempt at creating a single-page application, so I am really confused about design choice. Which one would be better, or can anyone suggest the standard way to go regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to create another object for the routing which depends on routing library such as SammyJS or CrossroadsJS.

Please refer my hobby project, [MyStory.Spa](https://github.com/RayKwon/MyStory.Spa), it is also single page application style web (not for the mobile app), which is using SammyJS for browser level routing.
In the MyStory.Spa architecture, webapp/app/infra/router.js takes a role for the routing and detailed information about routing, view, viewmodels are in the /webapp/app/infra/routing.table.js.

In this way you can decouple View, ViewModel, Model, Data Service, Routing and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting a few ideas from looking at your project structure. Would you happen to still have links to any resources/sites you used as references when making your app?

Comment: SPA course(http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/spa) in the pluralsight is a good referance although some of features are depending on asp.net mvc framework. And BoilerplateJS(https://github.com/ectechno/boilerplatejs) also could be a good referance. It provides some helper functions for the SPA and shows best practice for spa style apps